# POST request before bootstraping (or configuring) angular app

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angularjs

I need to receive some data from the server before starting angular application (it is accessToken that will be setup to all angular's http headers).

I tried with no luck to make this request in app's config section :( Maybe it's possible to make two angular apps, something like this *((!) almost pseudocode)*:

**boot.js**

```
var boot = angular.module('boot', []);
boot.getToken = function (callback) {
   boot.callback = callback;
};
boot.run(function ($http) {
   $http.post('/api/login', data).success(function (res) {
     // res.token save to storage/cookies etc.
     boot.callback();
   }); 
});
```

Main app.js start & bootstrap app etc.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['services', 'controllers', 'directives']);

app.init = function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
};
...
```

and in my require's main.js file:

**main.js**

```
...
require(['app', 'boot'], function (app, boot) {
  boot.getToken(function () {
    app.init();
  });
});
```

The main problem is that I need to bootstrap `boot.js` as well to use all angular's API..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, maybe will be helpful for someone - use `resolve` option on `$routeProvider.when()` method - it allows you to check and make necessary requests before preload your data from server into controller.